# How to recover damaged glibc on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, glibc, chroot

On a working Ubuntu 16.04 system, these commands were executed:

```
$ wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/glibc-2.26.tar.gz
$ tar -xvzf glibc-2.26.tar.gz
$ mkdir build_gcc && cd build_gcc
$ ../glibc-2.26/configure --prefix=/usr
$ make
$ sudo checkinstall
```

During install, errors were generated:

```
Makefile:106: recipe for target 'install-symbolic-link' failed
```

After that, not a single command was able to run, resulting in segmentation fault.

Obviously, `glibc` got damaged/overwritten with bad binaries. Now trying to recover the system by booting from a live Ubuntu flash and trying to reinstall `libc6`. These attemtps were made:

1. Downgrade libc6 and upgrade again:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get -o Dir=<partition_path> install libc6=2.23-0ubuntu3
   $ sudo apt-get -o Dir=<partition_path> install libc6
   ```

   This did not help, as trying to chroot into partition results in segfault:

   ```
   $ chroot <partition_path>
   ```
2. Use `apt-get -o RootDir`:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get -o RootDir=<partition_path> install libc6=2.23-0ubuntu3
   …
   Chrooting into <partition_path>
   E: Sub-process /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure —apt || true received a segmentation fault
   E: Failure running script /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure —apt || true
   ```

   As can be seen, it failed as well, because of chrooting into damaged environment.

How one should approach to recover the system?

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support.

Answer (score 3):

Use `apt-get download libc6` to get the package, then

```
dpkg -x libc6*.dpkg /partition_path
```

to "install" it.

Your assertion "Obviously, glibc got damaged/overwritten with bad binaries" is likely incorrect. What probably happened is that `libc.so.6` got new bits, while `ld-linux.so` did not, or vice versa. They *must* match at all times, or things break.